# Powershell foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to iterate through a list of users so I can pull their properties, but I am fairly new to Powershell and don't understand the output I'm getting.

```
foreach ($user in $AllUsers) 
{  
  get-member -inputobject $user; 
  write-host " "
}
```

The `$AllUsers` object has six users, each with a set of properties and methods.  However when I run the code block above, the output is six empty lines, then the list of properties and methods for each user six times in a row.  I am trying to get the properties and methods of each user separated out by a blank line.  Can someone help me understand why the output is running `write-host` six times and then `get-member` six times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the results of `Get-Member` are getting put into the pipeline and queued up until the block completes. In contrast, the side-effect of `Write-Host` is happening immediately on each loop. You can remedy this by writing to string output:

```
foreach($user in $AllUsers)
{
    $user | gm | out-string
}
```

This will print the members for each item with some whitespace in between. Most of the time all objects of a given type will have the same members, but occasionally there are dynamically defined members.

Comment: if for some reason write-host must be used to add content this will also print in the desired order

Answer (score 1):

It's behaving this way, because you told it too :)

When you use foreach, you are doing whatever's in the codeblock for each item in a collection ($AllUsers). So for each user, first a get-member is done, then write-host is writing an empty line.

Why would you want to write out the properties and methods for each user? They would be identical.

If you just want to list out the users with all the properties you can do this:

```
$AllUsers | format-list *
```

Then you can see all properties, when you have decided which one you want to display, you can choose to view only those:

```
$AllUsers | Select-Object Prop1,Prop2,Prop4,Prop10
```

Comment: There could be different members on each object added by PowerShell's extended type system. These can be added by the Add-Member cmdlet.

Comment: Haha I'm not yet at the extended type level in Powershell quite yet.  Ultimately I'm trying to pull a list of users from one AD and plug them into another.  I realize the list of properties and methods are going to be the same for each user, so the output of this particular command isn't necessary per say, but as I'm trying to build my loop for pulling out properties I ran into this and it threw me for a loop, so to speak.  I'm going to be using ojk's Select-Object though, it looks very useful.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Member` writes to the success output stream, whereas `Write-Host` writes to the console (or rather the host program). Different output is not guaranteed to be displayed in the order the respective statements were run. You can also get this behavior when you have statements write output to the success output stream as well as the error output stream (or one of the other output streams, like warning or debug). See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx) for a more thorough discussion of output in PowerShell.

If you want a blank line printed after each set of object members, replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output`:

```
foreach ($user in $AllUsers) {  
  Get-Member -InputObject $user
  Write-Output ''
}
```

You could also do something like this:

```
foreach ($user in $AllUsers) {  
  (Get-Member -InputObject $user) + ''
}
```

or like this:

```
$AllUsers | % { (Get-Member -InputObject $_) + '' }
```

Comment: That helps quite a bit thanks.  You and mike z are both correct but I gave him the right answer because it came first.